# WCF service - security in SOAP header

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-security

I’m trying to use a wcf service with UserNameOverTransport binding. I want my Soap header to look like this:

```
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"> 
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-        
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-14430313" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-   
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
<wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username> 
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-    token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password> 
<wsse:Nonce>OquGazmuMMHFrdeRQZGpkA==</wsse:Nonce> 
<wsu:Created>2009-08-25T19:17:07.369Z</wsu:Created> 
</wsse:UsernameToken> 
</wsse:Security>
```

My  SOAP looks like this:

```
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-    200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2011-07-  
29T10:38:58.452Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2011-07-
29T10:43:58.452Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-63332174-a7b4-  
4833-bd2e-32d0c0820f42-1"><o:Username>USERNAME</o:Username><o:Password 
Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile- 
1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</o:Password></o:UsernameToken></o:Security>
```

I have used

proxyclient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "USERNAME"
proxyclient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PASSWORD"

to insert username and password into the SOAP header, but I also need to insert wsse:Nonce and wsu:Created, how can I do that? And what is the diferense between using .ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName?

And how can I get the tags correct, wsse instead of o?

I’m using VS 2010 and VB.NET, and UserNameOverTransport binding. Do I have to install wse 3.0?

My app.config file looks like this:

```
<customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_IIntermediaryInboundExternal">
              <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" 
                  requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true"
                  keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="false"
                        replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite"
                        replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
                        sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
                        timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
                    <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
                        maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
                        negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
                        sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
                        reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
                        maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Default" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
            </binding>


<endpoint address="https://myendpointadress.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_mysevice"
            contract="myendpoint"
            name="CustomBinding_myendpoint" />
```

I hope someone can help me with this! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The namespace preffix is irrelevant. They both have the same namesapce uri, so are in the same namespace, regardless of the fact one uses an o prefix & the other uses wsse

Answer (score 5):

Standard WCF UserNameToken profile implementation in WCF doesn't use `Nonce` and `Created` = there is no way to force WCF to include them. Prefix doesn't matter that is just symbolic name defined in wrapper element and all correct XML parse implementations should work with both `wsse` or `o`.

The reason why WCF doesn't use `Nonce` and `Created` elements is because these elements should be used with `#PasswordDigest` type (which is not supported by WCF). Using them with `#PasswordText` doesn't make too much sense.

If your service requires `Nonce` and `Created` you must implement your own token instead of using standard WCF's user name implementation. [Here is example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/06/24/usernametoken-profile-vs-wcf.aspx) of building whole new UserNameToken profile implementation to support `#PasswordDigest`. It adds `Nonce` and `Created` elements as well.

Comment: Hi, and thanks a lot for your reply!!

I think I have to use Nonce and Created even if I use PasswordText. I’m new to WCF and I think it is a bit difficult to grasp all the security stuff. I added my services (WSHttpBinding) to the project and when I look at the app.config file my services is CustomBinding, is that ok?

Is it possible for you to give me a code example on how I can get all the information I need in the SOAP header (uname,passw,nonce,created), and how my app.config file must look like (according to how my app.config file looks like now, as I have shown you in my last post)?